# Django/Heroku Deployment issue OperationalError at / no such table: posts_post

Tags: python, html, django, heroku

OperationalError at /

no such table: posts_post

Django Version:     4.1
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:

no such table: posts_post

Exception Location:     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 357, in execute

Raised during:  posts.views.index
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python

Error during template rendering

In template /app/templates/index.html, error at line 31
no such table: posts_post
Code Highlighted in error is my Index.HTML File obj in object_list

```
       </section>
        <section class="featured-posts no-padding-top">
          <div class="container">
            <!-- Post-->
            {% for obj in object_list %}
          
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">
              {% if not forloop.first and not forloop.last %}
              <div class="image col-lg-5"><img src="{{ obj.thumbnail.url }}" alt="..."></div>
              {% endif %}
              <div class="text col-lg-7">
                <div class="text-inner d-flex align-items-center">
                  <div class="content">
                    <header class="post-header">
                      <div class="category">'''
```

Traceback to views.py file

/app/posts/views.py, line 51, in index( Highlighted line in error return render(request, 'index.html', context))

```
def index(request):
    featured = Post.objects.filter(featured=True)
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[0:3]

    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]
        new_signup = Signup()
        new_signup.email = email 
        new_signup.save()

    context = {
        'object_list': featured,
        'latest': latest
    }
    
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    
'''

I have tried solving it by removing pycache from my apps along with making migrations again however it throws same error..
Can anyone here help on this?

Thanks
```

Comment: (a) You can't use SQLite on Heroku. Switch to PostgreSQL or another client-server database. (b) You need to run your migrations on Heroku. See the marked duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for the advise.. i committed a locally developed sqlite db to my heroku git which made the error dissapear .. so i suppose i should remove that

Comment: Committing the file will make the error disappear, but the database file will be reset to whatever version is committed frequently and unpredictably. In other words, any records you save (e.g. posts you add) will disappear. You really want to use a client-server database with Heroku.